# How can I reuse functions for similar operations in C++

Tags: c++, function

For my uni we have an assignment atm that parses a .txt file into 2 structs of a state and counties. Afterwards we have several different needs of further evaluating the data such as sorting the states/counties by median household income. Unfortunately, I need to be able to perform each operation for both an array of states and an array of counties. Is there an efficient way to reuse my functions that use states and use them with counties, or do I have to overload my functions and write a lot more unneeded code. Here is an example function for use with states.

```
/*********************************************************************
** Function: print_lowest_2015
** Description: prints lowst unenmployment in 2015 from state
** Parameters: states and num
** Pre-Conditions: n/a
** Post-Conditions: n/a
*********************************************************************/
void print_lowest_2015(state* arr, int num) {
    int ue;
    string name;
    ue= arr[0].unemployed_2015;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if (arr[i].unemployed_2015 < ue) {
            ue = arr[i].unemployed_2015;
            name = arr[i].name;
        }
    }
    cout << "State with the lowest 2015 unemployment rate is " << name << " with a value of " << ue << endl;
}

/*********************************************************************
    ** Function: print_lowest_2015
    ** Description: prints lowst unenmployment in 2015 from counties
    ** Parameters: counties and num
    ** Pre-Conditions: n/a
    ** Post-Conditions: n/a
    *********************************************************************/
    void print_lowest_2015(county* arr, int num) {
        int ue;
        string name;
        ue = arr[0].unemployed_2015;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            if (arr[i].unemployed_2015 < ue) {
                ue = arr[i].unemployed_2015;
                name = arr[i].name;
            }
        }
        cout << "County with the lowest 2015 unemployment rate is " << name << " with a value of " << ue << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Generally, templates or polymorphism or a combination of the two would be used for this.  It's hard to advise without seeing an example operation for _both_ target structures.

Comment: You should update the variable med inside the if.

Comment: unfortunately our teacher hasn't gone over either of the above and i dont remember enough of the idea from java to attempt it, ill add what the county version would look like although it is almost the same

Comment: Do any of the text files contain any relation between `state` and `county`?

Comment: What is the actual difference between your `state` and `county` structures, besides their name?  It seems that your design might be over-complicated, since the structure seems to contain basic regional statistics and could presumably be used for any kind of region (state, county, city, empire, solar system...)

Comment: please post the struct definitions of state and country

Answer (score 0):

> void print_lowest_2015(state* arr, int num) {

Using a raw pointer for an array is not good c++. So don't bother improving it. Such code was written before 1998. Learning such code in 2019 is very dangerous and useless.

If for some reason you cannot change the calling code, here is how you write the function in reusable manner.

```
template<class Div>
void print_lowest_2015(Div* arr, int num) {
    auto min_div = std::min_element(arr, arr+num, [](Div& s1, Div& s2){
        return s1.unemployed_2015 < s2.unemployed_2015;
    });
    cout << "State with the lowest 2015 unemployment rate is " << min_div->name << " with a value of " << min_div->unemployed_2015 << '\n';
}
```

Link: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/70oMxs

Comment: Really appreciate your suggestion. But I think there is one issue in the code that you mentioned. And I want to highlight that. You have used `cout << "State with the lowest 2015 unemployment rate is " << min_div->name << " with a value of " << min_div->unemployed_2015 << '\n';` inside templated function. So, for County also, it would print `State`

Comment: "Learning such code in 2019 is very dangerous and useless." Legacy code exists. And people still write code like that for better or fire worse, often of they're trying to avoid template or minor performance overhead.

Comment: @George Yes. But the OP's question with 'states' and 'countries', is not legacy code. Also the question mentions it is part of assignment. So good to start learning with good practices.

Comment: @KunalPuri Yes, it is not possible to fix that without knowing the definitions of `state` and `country` and whether they can be modified.